# Why output of this C program is not correct

Tags: c

I have written a c program like this and expect to get correct outputs.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
     int t;
     scanf("%d", &t);
     int a[t-1], b[t-1];
     //printf("%d\n",sizeof(a) );
     do{
     scanf("%d %d", &a[t-1], &b[t-1]);
     }while(--t);

    do{
         printf("%d\n",a[t-1] + b[t-1]);
    }while(--t);

    return 0;
 }
```

But I am getting random values.What is wrong with this program?
The attempt is made to enter number of tries, then enter values , then print the addition of those values.

P.S
the array initialization is dynamic here.Is it valid?If not what should be the correct way?

Comment: What you program does, and what is your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "random values"? Also, you are modifying `t` in your first while loop. Once it reaches 0, the first loop will stop. The second loop will never run because `t` is 0.

Comment: `int a[t-1], b[t-1];` --> `int a[t], b[t], bk = t;`.. `t = bk;do{`

Comment: @Arc676 A `do...while` loop is guarenteed to run at least one time. That said, since the OP has UB earlier, anything could be the result.

Comment: Man, your code does not even compile, right? You can't declare an array size with a variable unless the array is dynamically allocated. Another bug in your code is that you modify your `t` variable in your first loop, where at the end of the loop `t == 0` therefore the second loop condition is false at the very begining. (Only happens once because of do-while).

Comment: the code does compile on my linux machine. I am declaring an array of fixed size.Yes the bugs are understood and solved.

Comment: @ProXicT The code will compile, with warnings (assuming they are enabled). Look up on VLAs.

Comment: gcc -Wall test17.c I am using this way to compile. No warnings.

Comment: @MloBootloader Oh. Sorry. Don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: @MloBootloader Sorry then, honestly, I didn't know about VLA's until now (MSVC doesn't even support it). Does it free the memory for you?

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.6.3 as compiler.

Comment: Its a compiler dependent problem in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare an array of length `10`, the index is from `0` to `9`. There is no index `10` for that array.

In your code, your array is of size `t-1`

```
int a[t-1], b[t-1];
```

So, in your first iteration, the `scanf()` and `printf()` statement accesses `a[t-1]`, which is not present. And, since its a `do while` loop, it is guaranteed to run atleast once.

Accessing array outside its bounds is [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, as Cool Guy pointed out in the comments, anything can happen.

Comment: a[t-1] is not present in scanf, how can it not be? if t is 10, then i am accessing a[9] that should be present? and how the next printf prints random values when t is already 0 from first do while loop. It should print only once.

Comment: @MloBootloader you declared your array as `int a[t-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Between reading all values and printing all values, you never reset `t` to it's original value. You will need to do that, probably using another variable to save it's original value.

Comment: @MloBootloader Yes. Just use one loop (after correcting the problems).

Comment: @MloBootloader You can do it without using an extra variable like [this](http://ideone.com/aQcPRi), but note that the input is stored in reverse order, i.e, the first input is stored in the last slot of the array while the last input is stored in the first slot of the array.

Comment: actually I have to print in the same order as I have done. all inputs must be put first and outputs in last. I have to use one extra variable.

Comment: @MloBootloader If so, use an extra variable and two `while`/`for` loop instead of two `do...while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

The array size should be a constant, it cant be set at run time. For run time memory allocation you need to use pointer variable with malloc function. So first of all you need to assign a constant value to variable t at time of declaration.

Just a tip, always try to declare and initialize the variable before any statements. The array initialization should come before scanf, by doing this you can clearly see the problem i.e you are allocating memory(some random) and then getting value from the user. The compiler must be doing the similar thing, allocating some random size memory and then getting the value t, now this value t will only be used in your iterations and not for array allocation as arrays are allocated before with some rand size (what ever garbage value t is pointing to at time of its declaration). Sometime the program will be displaying some random values and sometime it could crash on accessing a memory that's out of bound.

Comment: I think this depends on compiler. I remember I had this problem before and then this feature was just been added to new compilers and I also learned that we can't do this thing. I am revising c again and today I do not face any problem with variable length array with my gcc version 4.6.3.

Comment: calculate number of elements in the array a just before first iteration and print the value, re run your program many times. The elements value should not be similar to what you entered in first scanf, which means it could lead to crash but  if it is similar then !! ... for element calculation you may use this statement; int num_of_ele = 0; num_of_ele = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);